# Cannot read property from JSON Array

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a text based game with Javscript and I am having some issues with referencing a JSON array.

```
var cRecipes = [];
    function craftItem(id){ 
        var n = cRecipes[id].name;
        var t = cRecipes[id].type;
        var i1 = cRecipes[id].item1;
        var a1 = parseInt(cRecipes[id].amount1);
        var i2 = cRecipes[id].item2;
        var a2 = parseInt(cRecipes[id].amount2);
        for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
            if (inventory[i].item == i1 && inventory[i].amount >= a1){
                var inv1 = parseInt(inventory[i].amount)
                parseInt(inventory[i].amount) -= a1;
                a1 = 0;
            }
            if (inventory[i].item == i2 && inventory[i].amount >= a2){
                parseInt(inventory[i].amount) -= a2;
                a2 = 0;
            }
        }
        if (a1 == 0 && a2 == 0){
            if (t == "Hat"){
                cHat = products[rId].name;
                command(products[rId].effect);
                p(n + " crafted");
            }
            else {
                p("Insufficient items");
            }
        }
    }
    function loadCrafting(){
        cRecipes = [
        {"name":"Mega Fedora", "type":"Hat", "item1": "Euphorite", "amount1":4, "item2":"Essence Of Euphoria", "amount2":2, "effect":""},
        {"name":"Mega Fedora 2", "type":"Hat", "item1": "Euphorite", "amount1":4, "item2":"Essence Of Euphoria", "amount2":2, "effect":""},
        ];   
        c();
        p("-- Your Crafting --");
        back();
        for (cr = 0; cr < cRecipes.length; cr++){
            p("<span class='choice' id='c"+ cr + "'>" + cRecipes[cr].name +", " + cRecipes[cr].type + ", " + cRecipes[cr].item1 + " x" + cRecipes[cr].amount1 + ", " + cRecipes[cr].item2 + " x" + cRecipes[cr].amount2 + "</span>");
            $("#c" + cr).click(function(){craftItem(cr);});

        }
    }
```

When running the script, I am given the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I have used similar methods with other parts of my game and have had no issues so this

Comment: Take chrome dev tools debugger and debug your program step by step. PS: there is no JSON in your code.

Comment: Also, note that you loop variables are all leaking, you need `var`, so `for(var i=0` and `for(var cr=0`

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is coming from `cRecipes[id].name`? I also see `products[rId].name` but no mention of a `products` object, nor `rId`

Comment: @zerkms obviously the OP is referring to the object literal, not actual JSON

Comment: @jasonscript: obviously - yes, that's why we need to teach them to use proper terms.

Comment: try `var obj = JSON.parse(cRecipes[id])` to access the propertive

Comment: @jasonscript: you see - they even give advices to use `JSON.parse()` :-D

Comment: @zerkms ok, you win :)